# Label does not change content

Tags: wpf, label

I have WPF app with label MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,17,0,16" Name="lblLoadDriver" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" Width="10"></Label>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs there is code, after button click:

```
lblLoadDriver.Content = ""+DriverInstance.GetType().ToString();
```

When i debug, I put the mouse over the value of lblLoadDriver browse under "base" section and see content is AS-I-NEED.. i see the text ok, but it didnt change the text on GUI.
Why is this ? Do i need to refresh gui or something ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because of `Width="10"`?

Also `Height="10"` is a strange idea.

Comment: tnx didnt notice dont know why it was 10 !!